# Prevent Safari From Saving Search History

Tags: windows, macos, safari

Is there a way to prevent Safari from saving the search history on the browser toolbar? I see where you can clear the previous search history, but I would like to prevent it from saving at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Private browsing (Safari>Private Browsing...) will do it. However, this prevents all history and cookies from saving as well.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted something more granular.